# Python GUI - entry values are not strings but methods?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a small problem with my program :
I can't to understand how to reuse the entered values in the program. It says that I cannot use float on a method, but I thought that the s.get gave me a string. It also seems that it doesn't actually use the values entered but just the default values.
Does anyone know what is wrong with the code?

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root      = Tk()
        self.labelVariable = StringVar()
        self.root.title('Projet informatique')
        self.initialize()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def initialize(self):
        self.main = Frame(self.root)
        self.main.pack() 

        label = Label(self.main, textvariable=self.labelVariable, font=('courier',10,'bold'), anchor="w", fg="red", bg="white")
        label.pack()

        self.labelVariable.set(u"Modélisation de populations atteintes d'un virus")

        v=Listbox(self.main)
        v.insert("end","Modèle SIR")
        v.insert("end", "Modèle de Witowski")
        v.insert("end", "Modèle de Munz")
        v.insert("end", "Modèle avec traitement")
        v.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.Double) 
        v.pack(expand=1,fill=BOTH)


    def Double(self,event):
        widget    = event.widget
        selection = widget.curselection()
        value     = widget.get(selection[0])
        self.newWindow(value)

    def ModifyTextarea(self,elem,msg,clear=None):
        elem.config(state=NORMAL)
        if clear:
            elem.delete(1.0, END)
        else:
           elem.insert(END,msg)
        elem.config(state=DISABLED)
    def newWindow(self,msg):
        top = Toplevel(self.root)
        q1 = Frame(top)
        q1.pack()
        top.grab_set()
        text = Text(q1,state=DISABLED,exportselection=True)
        text.pack()
        lbl = Label(q1,text="")
        lbl.pack()
        self.ModifyTextarea(text,msg)

        v2=StringVar()
        v3=StringVar()
        v4=StringVar()
        v5=StringVar()
        v1=StringVar()
        v6=StringVar()
        e1=Entry(q1,textvariable=v1)
        e2=Entry(q1,textvariable=v2)
        e3=Entry(q1,textvariable=v3)
        e4=Entry(q1,textvariable=v4)
        e5=Entry(q1,textvariable=v5)
        e6=Entry(q1,textvariable=v6)
        e1.pack()
        e2.pack()
        e3.pack()
        e4.pack()
        e5.pack()
        e6.pack()
        v1.set("Taux de mortalité des zombies")
        v2.set("Coefficient de propagation du virus")
        v3.set("Taux de rémission")
        v4.set("Taux d'infectés devenant malades")
        v5.set("Taux de guérison")
        v6.set("Pas de temps")

        a=v1.get
        b=v2.get
        ze=v3.get
        T=v4.get
        N=v5.get
        dt=v6.get
        def callback():
            print (a,b,ze,T,N,dt)

        btnquit = Button(q1,width = 1,text = "Ok",command =callback())
        btnquit.pack()


        def zombies(a,b,ze,T,N,dt) :
            a=flot(a)
            b=float(b)
            ze=float(ze)
            T=float(T)
            N=float(N)
            dt=float(dt)
            n = T/dt
            n=int(n)
            t=np.zeros((n+1))
            for i in range (0,n):
                t[0]=0
                t[i+1]=t[i]+dt
            s = np.zeros((n+1))
            z = np.zeros((n+1))
            r = np.zeros((n+1))
            s[0] = N-1
            z[0] =1
            r[0] = 0

            for i in range (n-1):
                s[i+1] = s[i] + dt*(-b*s[i]*z[i])
                z[i+1] = z[i] + dt*(b*s[i]*z[i]-a*s[i]*z[i]+ze*r[i])
                r[i+1] = r[i] + dt*(a*s[i]*z[i]- ze*r[i])

                if s[i+1]<0 or s[i+1] >N:
                    s[i+1]=0
                    break

                if z[i+1] > N or z[i+1] < 0:
                    z[i+1]=0
                    break

                if r[i+1] <0 or r[i+1] >N:
                    r[i+1]=0
                    break
                return (t,s,r,z,i+2)

        t,s,r,z,i=zombies(a,b,ze,T,N,dt)
        plt.plot(t[:i],s[:i],'b')
        plt.plot(t[:i],z[:i],'r')
        plt.plot(t[:i],r[:i],'y')
        plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = GUI()
```

Answer (score 1):

These are all incorrect:

```
a=v1.get
b=v2.get
ze=v3.get
T=v4.get
N=v5.get
dt=v6.get
```

You aren't calling the `get` function. To call it, add parenthesis:

```
a=v1.get()
...
```

FWIW, you don't need to use StringVars for each entry widget. You can just as easily get the value directly from the widget. Using StringVar often just adds extra code and extra objects to manage with no real benefit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are just referencing the `get` methods, but not calling them. Also, you should make sure to call those functions *inside* your callback function, otherwise you will always print the values those variables had when you initialized your UI. Finally, note that instead of binding the `callback` to the button, you are executing the function once and binding its *result* to the button.

```
def callback():
    # here, you have to ADD () to get the result of get
    print(v1.get(), v2.get(), v3.get(), v4.get(), v5.get(), v6.get())

# here, you have to REMOVE () to get the callback function itself
btnquit = Button(q1, width=1, text="Ok", command=callback)
```

Similarly in your `zombies` function:

```
def zombies(): # no need for input parameters
    a = float(v1.get())
    b = float(v2.get())
    etc.
```

And finally, you have to bind that function to a button (maybe instead of that `callback` function?), otherwise `zombies` will be executed just once at the end of the `newWindow` method, i.e. before inputting any actual data. The plotting should probably also be part of that function.

Comment: I tried doing this, but : a = float(v1.get()) does not convert my string into a float. I have changed the button into btnquit = Button(q1,width = 1,text = "Ok",command = zombies() ) but the button doesn't show up in the window anymore. What am I doing wrong (again)?

Comment: @Doule What do you mean, "does not convert into a float"? Do you get an exception? Also, you are _again_ assigning the result of `zombies()` to the button's `command`, and since the result is a tuple of numbers in this case, this will likely raise an exception. Try `Button(..., command=zombies)` and make sure that `zombies` does not take input parameters, otherwise you have to use a lambda to provide those.

Comment: I get an error saying it cannot convert v1.get into a float.

Comment: @Doule Are you by any chance doing `float(v1.get)`? It has to be `float(v1.get())`, mind the parentheses! If that still not works, do `print(repr(v1.get()))` to see what the content of that variable is.

Comment: This is what I get : a=float(v1.get())
ValueError: could not convert string to float. It looks like it is running zombies before I even press "ok"

Comment: @Doule Because, as I said before, you are doing `,command = zombies() )`, thus _calling_ `zombies` when you initialize your UI and binding the _result_ of that to `command`.

Comment: I have tried every combination I know. I have followed your instructions, there are no parenthesis after command = zombies but it still reads zombies before I can input anything. What am I doing wring ?

Comment: @Doule I don't know, without seeing what you did. Maybe you should post an updated version of your code in your question (but please do not remove the original code, as this would invalidate all the answers), or ask a new question with your updated code, if the changes are more significant.